# 404 Cannot POST Using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I´m trying to create an API Rest in NodeJs with Express.

I have my **index.js** with the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const routesV1 = require('./routes/v1/index');

const app = express();

routesV1(app);

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Running on port: 4000');
});
```

then i have a routes folder with another "index.js" and a "usersRoutes".

Here´s the code of the userRoutes:

```
const express = require('express');

const userController = require('../../controllers/v1/UserController');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/create', userController.createUser);
router.post('/update', userController.updateUser);
router.post('/delete', userController.deleteUser);
router.get('/get-all', userController.getUsers);

module.exports = router;
```

and the code of the index.js into the routes folder:

```
const userRoutes = require('./UserRoutes');
const productRoutes = require('./ProductRoutes');

module.exports = app => {
  app.use('api/v1/users', userRoutes);
};
```

but when i´m consuming via Postman, with the following url: http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users/create I´m receiving a 404 error code.

Can anybody help me? thanks

Comment: Are you using POST request from Postman?

Comment: @devcass yes!..

Comment: Put your main file (start server) in the question, please

Comment: @devcass according to my package.json file, the main in my project is the index.js file corresponding to the first fragment of code that I attach in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it adding '/' to the route in **routes/index.js**

```
const userRoutes = require('./UserRoutes');
const productRoutes = require('./ProductRoutes');

module.exports = app => {
  app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoutes);
  app.use('/api/v1/products', productRoutes);
};
```